# .net webbrowser control: monitoring http request (post get)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, http, request

I am working on a program using vb.net that allows me to browse a website using the webbrowser control. as part of my activity, I will download some stuff from the website by entering information into a form and then clicking a download button. There is then a bunch of access to some server side php scripts and then the browser opens the file save dialog to download a file. Now what I want to be able to do is watch the get/post requests as the control is interacting with the server at the other end, as one of the 'get' requests contains the filename. I then want to extract the file name and use that to manipulate the file after it is downloaded, but I really have no idea how to use it. I've tried looking all over for this, and probably the closest I have got is this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/157329/Http-Monitor-for-Webbrowser-Control

but I am using windows 7 and visual studio 2013 express and it won't even compile.

does anyone have any idea whether what I want to do is even possible using this control (I know it is doable in theory, as I watch the network activity using firefox)

thanks!

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: the compile error is cannot open include file 'atlbase.h'

Comment: add that to your question... This is not my domain of expertise so I can't help you; but if your question is better formatted you are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: I don't really want to rely on this particular thing from codeproject though. It's more trying to find out how I can intercept posts and gets using a visual studio based webbrowser without having to program a custom web browser. It's a bit frustrating as firefox does it without any problem, but I need my particular bit of software to do it!